# finite/infinite sets and their cardinality (involving functions)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to show this:

Let $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 3|x \}$ and $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Show that $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality.

I know that when $a \in A \geq 0$, every element in $A$ maps to a unique element in $\mathbb{N}$. For example, $(0,0),(3,1),(6,2),(9,3)$, etc. Which means when $a \in A \geq 0$ it's a bijection from $A \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ (right?).

But I'm not sure how to show that the negative values in $A$ map to unique values in $\mathbb{N}$ or just in general how cardinality of an infinite set can be the same as a finite set.

Comment: What does "$A\ge0$" even mean? $A$ is a set and $0$ is a number, right? What does it mean for a set to be greater than a number? And what does $f$ have to do with anything? What would be the difference if the problem just read: "Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb Z:3|x\}.$ Show that $A$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality."?

Comment: I meant $a \in A \geq 0$. And as far as the function part, that's how the question was stated.

Comment: The elements of $A$ are $0,-3,3,-6,6,-9,9,-12,12,\dots,$ right? So how about $(0,0),(-3,1),(3,2),(-6,3),(6,4),(-9,5),(9,6),(-12,7),(12,8),\dots?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A = \{X \in \mathbb{Z}: 3 | x\} = \{0,3,-3,6,6, 9,-9,12,-12,15, -15,\ldots \}$.

It's clear there is a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$, map $f(3n)$ to $2n$ and $f(-3n)$ to $2n-1$, so $0 \rightarrow 0$, $3 \rightarrow 2$, $-3 \rightarrow 1$, $6 \rightarrow 4$, $-6 \rightarrow 3$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality of an infinite set cannot be the same as a finite set - that's what "infinite" means. None of the sets you're talking about are finite, though, so that's not a problem.

Think about how to map $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. You could try just mapping the nonnegative integers to themselves, but then you don't have anywhere to put the negative ones. So you need to open up some space. If you send $n$ to $2n$ whenever $n \geq 0$, there's room - all of the odd numbers. So here's your bijection: $f(n) = 2n$ if $n \geq 0$ and $-2n - 1$ if $n < 0$.

Try using the same sort of approach to make a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{N}$ - it's a very similar situation.